# Why am i getting this clang error: _fwrite$UNIX2003 on simulator with iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios8

I have downloaded the new iOS 8 into both my phone and the latest Xcode onto my Mac. It all works fine but after loading up and trying the new iPhone 6 plus simulator when I try the iPhone 4s or 5 simulators (it works with 5s) I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_fwrite$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::~PosixEnv() in Firebase(env_posix.o)
      leveldb::(anonymous namespace)::PosixEnv::~PosixEnv() in Firebase(env_posix.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems very odd to me that I have been using the iPhone 4 simulator all morning but it is only after I try the iPhone 6 plus simulator that it breaks and I can't get its usage back

Comment: possible duplicate of [fopen$UNIX2003 fails inside external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856848/fopenunix2003-fails-inside-external-library)

Comment: Although you have posted a duplicate answer the question certainly isn't a duplicate - one referring to this error with regard to iOS 8 and the simulator, the other referring to using an external static library

Comment: The question clearly is a duplicate.  Both are about linking errors linking a simulator app against the iOS 8 Simulator SDK using a static archive compiled against the OS X SDK.

Comment: But the other question was posted 18 months before iOS8 was released

Comment: Ah yes, so that one was actually referring to seeing the issue with iOS 7.1 (where it was just a runtime error and not a linktime error), but the issue is still the same.  Developers trying to use code built against an OS X SDK for apps in the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer provided in [this link](http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/35905/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-xcode-6-ios-8-beta-6) worked fine for me.

As per above link ,
In order to remove all of these error you have to create a *.c file (doesn't need a specific name) and copy paste the bellow code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

int fputs$UNIX2003(const char *res1, FILE *res2){
    return fputs(res1,res2);
}

int nanosleep$UNIX2003(int val){
    return usleep(val);
}

char* strerror$UNIX2003(int errornum){
    return strerror(errornum);
}

double strtod$UNIX2003(const char *nptr, char **endptr){
    return strtod(nptr, endptr);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}
```

normally everything should be ok.

Comment: Any possibility adding this file to the project can affect Apple to reject the app ?

Answer (score 5):

fwrite$UNIX2003 is a symbol that is provided by OS X and is not part of the iOS Simulator runtime.  iOS is *always* conformant and thus does not have legacy (non $UNIX2003) variants of functions (which are provided for binary compatibility with code built against older versions of the OS X SDK).

The common cause of the issue you are seeing is that you have an object file or archive (env_posix.o or a libsomething.a that contains env_posix.o) that was built against the OS X SDK and are trying to link it into your iOS Simulator executable.  That is not supported as the two platforms are not binary compatible at that layer.

You need to rebuild env_posix.o against the iOS Simulator SDK.

Comment: please tell me how to rebuild libsomething.a

Comment: @hardikvyas You just need to rebuild your code against the appropriate SDK.  I can’t give you more specific instructions than that because it would depend on your particular case.

Comment: Thanx I will Try That