# iOS simulator crashes when invoking fcntl() - symbol not present

Tags: xcode, linker, ios-simulator

The full error message I get in the XCode console:

**Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
fcntl$UNIX2003 called from function su_setblocking in image test-ios-client.**

*Please note that the same code works fine on the actual device (i.e. iPhone and iPad).*

The details:

fcntl() is not invoked directly from my code, but from code inside a static library that I use (Sofia SIP). So what I've done is that I have built the Sofia SIP static library for all architectures I intend to run on (i.e. armv7 for the devices and i386 and x86_64 for the 32bit and 64bit simulator), created a 'fat' library with lipo and then link against that static library in XCode. Code works fine for the actual devices, but for the simulator (both 32bit and 64bit) I get the runtime issue I pasted above.

It is as if the library that contains the definition of fcntl is not linked with my App, but only for the Simulator. But this is very strange because fcntl is a standard call, it should be there by default (plus, again, it works for the device). I also tried manually linking various other libraries available in XCode but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am i getting this clang error: \_fwrite$UNIX2003 on simulator with iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966817/why-am-i-getting-this-clang-error-fwriteunix2003-on-simulator-with-ios-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Why am i getting this clang error: _fwrite$UNIX2003 on simulator with iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966817/why-am-i-getting-this-clang-error-fwriteunix2003-on-simulator-with-ios-8/26005544#26005544)

The static library that you are using was built for OS X and not the iOS Simulator.  You need to rebuild that static library against the iOS Simulator SDK (or get the vendor to provide you an appropriate build for iOS).

Comment: That was it! Apparently the script I used to setup the Simulator environment for the command-line build of the library was messed up. I changed it to point properly to the Simulator libs, binaries, etc and now it works fine. Thanks!