# Iphone simulator (linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

I am using Unity to build iPhone game. When I build for iPhone simulator I got this annouing error:
I tried to build for iOS 4.2 and later versions... but no hope..

```
ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: can you include relevant code?

Comment: I'm designing my game in Unity game engine.. However I used to run it on my real iPhone device without any error. Now I want to run it on iOS simulator.

Comment: what do you mean by relevant code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fopen$UNIX2003 fails inside external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856848/fopenunix2003-fails-inside-external-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that you are trying to link a static archive that was built against the OS X SDK into your iOS Simulator executable.  Previous versions of Xcode's toolchain did not guard against this (which can lead to various runtime issues where there are binary incompatibilities between the two platforms).

Your clock$UNIX2003 implementation hack is simply masking the larger issue.

You need to get a version of that library built against the iOS Simulator SDK for use in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Yes you are right... I just got Unity update, and this issue fixed.. the update can be found here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-patch-releases.246198/#post-1778651

Answer (score -1):

I finally Found a work around !
form this post :
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios8-xcode6-compatibility.249533/page-2

just add this code to the end of main.mm in Xcode project

```
#include <time.h>

extern "C"
{
clock_t
clock$UNIX2003(void)
{
    return clock();
}
}
```

Comment: NO!  Absolutely NOT!  That is a horrible workaround.  That indicates that you likely are using a static archive (libsomething.a) which was built against the Mac OS X SDK and are trying to link it into an iOS Simulator executable.  Don't do that!