# I've just upgraded to xcode 6.0 and I can no longer deploy to iPhone, I get a Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6

When I do following instructions

```
Ld /Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/NameProject.app/NameProject normal x86_64
cd /Users/bryanvanzandt/Desktop/names/rit_Archive_final
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=3.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Intermediates/NAME\ GENERATOR.build/Release-iphonesimulator/NameProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NameProject.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=3.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AVFoundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Intermediates/NAME\ GENERATOR.build/Release-iphonesimulator/NameProject.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NameProject_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/bryanvanzandt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NAME_GENERATOR-cnehwuuxswlygfalncakoblvfwjp/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/NameProject.app/NameProject
```

I get this error

> ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone simulator (linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998545/iphone-simulator-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocati)

Answer (score 0):

The link error is caused by trying to use the `-pie` option when trying to create an executable that is targeted at iOS 3.2. Chances are that you can fix this just by adjusting your deployment target which can be found in the **Project** settings for your app in the **Build Settings** tab.

If, however, you need to build for iOS 3.2 (seems unlikely), you can turn on `Don't Build Position Independent Executable` in the **Linking** section.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Go to your deployment target and change from 3.2 to 4.2 or later. Do not mind about build settings or anything else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and changing the target didn't seem the work. The problem is actually that IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET may be set twice in the project file- once for debug, once for release, and you have to change both values.

In the Search tab, type TARGET. Go to both places where it is set and change both to higher values.