# dyld: Symbol not found: _timezone$UNIX2003

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

We are trying to move an existing iPad project up to XCode 6.  Everything is well under XCode 5.

When I build for "iPad Retina 7.1" simulator, the app builds and works just fine.

However, when I build for "iPad Retina 8.0" simulator, I get the following upon launching the app:

dyld: Symbol not found: _timezone$UNIX2003
  Referenced from: /Users/Tim/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D99BBC17-1E88-41DF-ADB2-06CB6DAA96CD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6CB6E0FE-46A3-4E74-8DAA-2F345C931617/SongBook.app/SongBook
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
 in /Users/Tim/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D99BBC17-1E88-41DF-ADB2-06CB6DAA96CD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6CB6E0FE-46A3-4E74-8DAA-2F345C931617/SongBook.app/SongBook

Google has not led to any enlightening results, and searching our code for 'timezone' does not lead to anything enlightening either.

Thanks for any and all leads ;)

Comment: Try a clean (command-K) and a build folder clean (command-shift-option-K). Let me know if either of those works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Undo- thanks for your suggestion.  Just tried both and no such luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fopen$UNIX2003 fails inside external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856848/fopenunix2003-fails-inside-external-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_timezone$UNIX2003 is not relevant for the iOS Simulator runtime.  This error indicates that you have some code built against the OS X SDK linked into your iOS Simualtor app.  Do you have a static archive (libsomething.a) that you are linking into your app while building against the iOS 7.1 SDK?

I would expect the iOS 8.0 SDK should give you an appropriate error at build time or at runtime, whereas iOS 7.1 would let your app build and only abort if the invalid function was actually called.